# SEO URLs with htaccess conflict issues

Tags: .htaccess

I've got a small glitch with my .htaccess. I googled and tried few things without any result so I had to turn to **SOF** for help.

Consider following htaccess rule;

```
# CATEGORY LISTING
ReWriteRule ^listing/category/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*) ?module=listing&type=category&get=$1&c_id=$2&c_name=$3&page=$4 [L]

ReWriteRule ^listing/category/(.*)/(.*)/(.*) ?module=listing&type=category&get=$1&c_id=$2&c_name=$3 [L]

# CATEGORY FILTER
ReWriteRule ^listing/category/(.*)/(.*)/(.*) ?module=listing&type=category&orderType=$1&order=$2&page=$3 [L]

ReWriteRule ^listing/category(.*)/(.*) ?module=listing&type=category&orderType=$1&order=$2 [L]

ReWriteRule ^listing/category/(.*) ?module=listing&type=category&page=$1 [L]

ReWriteRule ^listing/category ?module=listing&type=category [L]
```

Problem here is with 2 rules are conflicting with each other;

This rule;

```
ReWriteRule ^listing/category/(.*)/(.*)/(.*) ?module=listing&type=category&get=$1&c_id=$2&c_name=$3 [L]
```

Conflicts with this rule;

```
ReWriteRule ^listing/category/(.*)/(.*)/(.*) ?module=listing&type=category&orderType=$1&order=$2&page=$3 [L]
```

Is there anyway to solve this conflict?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: ¿What conflict? You know there is a conflict but don't explain why or what do you expect to happen with each of the conflicting rules. Maybe if you give some examples of the incoming URLs, people can understand what the rules are supposed to do.

Comment: Hello faa, firstly thank you for taking your time to read my problem and leaving a comment. I thought it was pretty clear as Jon explained that since the build is the same, second rule never applies. That was the problem / conflict. Thank you for your time.

Comment: It is pretty clear now, but I made my comment 2 hours before the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there anyway to solve this conflict?

To solve this, you need to make the URI for the `get` query string and `order` query string mutually exclusive. You have exactly the same regular expression for both of them, so the second one will **never** be applied because anything that would match the second one will simply be handled by the first one.

For example, you can make one of them look like: `/order/category/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)` and the other `/listing/category/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)`. Those two URI's are mutually exclusive and will never conflict.

Additionally, you should change all of your `(.*)` to `([^/]*)`, because `(.*)` isn't greedy and will gobble up additional path.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Jon. I'm using MVC build so listing part of the url includes the page 'listing.php'. If I were to change it to 'order' it will try to include 'order.php' which will cause error. However if I don't have any other work around, I will play with it from PHP side to include 'listing.php' instead of 'order.php'. Thank you for your time to help me out with this problem Jon. Much appreciated.

Comment: +1 Really hard to figure it out. For me, at least. Great deduction, as usual.